# Buggy IntervalUnion with Quantities?

Tags: units, arithmetic, intervals

`IntervalUnion` can give wrong output when used with `Quantity`:

```
IntervalUnion[Quantity[Interval[{0, 1}], "Seconds"], 
 Quantity[Interval[{4, 5}], "Seconds"]]
```

> Quantity[Interval[List[0,5]],"Seconds"]

Whereas

```
IntervalUnion[Interval[{0, 1}], Interval[{4, 5}]]
```

> Interval[{0,1},{4,5}]

So this error is unbounded.

Spot-checking `IntervalIntersection` seems ok. Does anyone know of similar issues with `Interval` arithmetic over `Quantities`?

Comment: I reported to tech support.